# Disable dragging for all images

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I want to disable dragging on all images on a particular page. I've made this work with `ondragstart="return false"`, but I hate working with HTML attributes when I can make it work with JQuery (especially since it involves a lot of images). The code I've got is:

```
const img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].addEventListener("drag", function(a) {
        a.preventDefault;
    });
}
```

When I look in the developer tools I can see the event listener on every image, but I can still drag them. What's going on here?
By the way, I've also tried `function() {return false}`.

Comment: if you are preventing them to copy the image to there computer You will only be making other ppl annoyed by doing so and they will find a other way to get it. Putting stuff up on the web means you will share stuff to the world.

Comment: @Endless I wanted the images to look like buttons, and they won't feel like that if you can drag them around like normal images. By the way, the images aren't that special, so I doubt anyone would want to download them...

Comment: Did you try `img[i].addEventListener("dragstart"...` ?  `drag` is fired whilst dragging, so dragstart is probably tidier.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

[HTML ondragstart Event Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_ondragstart.asp)

```
<body>
    <img src="html5.png" id="html5" width="256px" height="256px" alt="HTML5" />
</body>

<script>
    document.getElementById('html5').ondragstart = function () { return false; };
</script>
```

Comment: That only disables dragging on the image with id 'html5'. I'm trying to disable dragging on **all** images on the page.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class_values");
```

[How to “get” elements](http://xahlee.info/js/js_get_elements.html)